# Git submodule management strategy

Tags: git, git-submodules, smartgit

We use GIT to manage our project.

Each project has a "core" (like a framework from who we'll built the project) So each project has at least 2 remotes branches:

- 1 repository for that core framework.
- 1 repository per client project.

We also have modules. Each module have a core that contain the basic functionnality, and we personnalize each module from that base for each client.

- So we have submodules that are included in each client project
- But I can't figure out how to handle the personnalization part of the submodules.

How can GIT help me if I want to add some new files in a submodule that must be used only in 1 particular client project ?

As thoses files are personnalized for the main project, the best case would be to commit some files contained inside the submodule in the client project branch, but it looks like I can't as each submodule are independent.

Ps.: We use SmartGit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scenario where you can use git-subtree (merging)

> If you made changes to the other
>   project in your repository, they may
>   want to merge from your project. This
>   is possible using subtree — it can
>   shift up the paths in your tree and
>   then they can merge only the relevant
>   parts of your tree.

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html

> The idea of the subtree merge is that
>   you have two projects, and one of the
>   projects maps to a subdirectory of the
>   other one and vice versa. When you
>   specify a subtree merge, Git is smart
>   enough to figure out that one is a
>   subtree of the other and merge
>   appropriately — it’s pretty amazing.

http://progit.org/book/ch6-7.html

But I suppose you want to use submodules and not move away from it.

Comment: My only interest in submodule is because if we fix something in the core of a module, it's really easy to apply the change in every projects.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't as each submodule are independent.

While it is true a submodule is "independent", since it has its own set of commits and branches as an individual repository, you still can define a client-project branch on said submodule.

That branch would be defined in your main client-project repo, as well as in the core submodule, in order to isolate changes specific to a client project done in both repos.
When you push back those changes done in the core submodules, you push them in a client-project branch whose name matches the name of the client branch used in your client parent repo.

So in short, a naming convention might help you isolate small specific changes done in a core submodule used and shared by many client-project repos.

Comment: But the branches must be remote to be shared between all developper. So does that mean that I'll have to create 1 repository per submodule version for each client ? So if I use 10 submodules, I'll have to create 11 repositories to handle 1 project ?

Comment: @FMaz008: "1 repository per submodule": a submodule *is* a repo already. If you are using 10 submodules in a project client, you are referencing them in your `.submodules` file. Each branches, created either in the parent repo or in one of the submodules, will be shared once pushed to their respective upstream repo.

Comment: Yes, that part I understand. So that confirm that I'll have to create as much repository as I'll have submodules for each project.

Comment: @FMaz008: I am not sure what you mean by "creating a repo": they should already exist. What you will do is getting a local working directory filled with a parent repo, and recursively by all the submodules repo referenced by the parent repo. Each client project will use directly only one repo (a client-project repo) with in each of those references to all the core submodules you need.

Comment: What you described sound like my actual setup. But the problem is that when I modify something specific for the client 1 project in a submodule referenced in that project, it get pushed to the submodule repository. So when I go in the client2 project and pull, I get the specific modification :( . The problem: I'm unable to distinguish the Core from the Specifics.